# Как вывести id последней вставленной записи в переменную типа string?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Есть запрос на вставку записи:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("INSERT INTO Passanger (Fname, Sname, Lname, NumberPass, WhoPass, WherePass) " +
                "VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}')", Fname, Sname, Lname, NumberPass, WhoPass, WherePass), conn);
```

Как вывести id этой записи в переменную? Читал что через `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` можно но не понял как корректно записать. ID в БД присваевается автоматически к записи (счетчик).

Comment: А у вас там данные на спецсимволы проверяются вообще? Инъекция же готовая...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, вот так:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
  $"INSERT INTO Passanger (Fname, Sname, Lname, NumberPass, WhoPass, WherePass) 
  VALUES ({Fname}, {Sname}, {LName}, {NumberPass}, {WhoPass}, {WherePass})
  SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS varchar(max))", conn)
string result = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Более безопасный способ - выбирать `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` а не `@@Identity`. Если на таблице будет триггер, который сделает еще одну вставку куда-нибудь, то `@@Identity` вернет левое значение, а `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` - правильное.

Comment: Вы правы, поправил.

Comment: Вы уверены, что использование `GO` тут допустимо?

Comment: @Yaant Попробовал - действительно с GO выбрасывается исключение. Кроме того, необходимо результат функции SCOPE_IDENTITY() конвертировать на уровне MSSQL.

Comment: `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()` требует ссылку на объект, как исправить?

Comment: @Денис а подумать? Не верю, что вы первый раз этот метод видите...

Answer (score 1):

Или вот так:

```
INSERT INTO Passanger (Fname, Sname, Lname, NumberPass, WhoPass, WherePass)
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id
VALUES (@fname, @sname, @lname, @numberPass, @whoPass, @wherePass)
```

Comment: немного не понял как вывести inserted.id в переменную типа стринг?

Comment: @Денис так же, как делается любой другой SQL-запрос. Например, методом `ExecuteScalar()`

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте в самом конце запроса `; select @@IDENTITY`
И запрос выполняйте как чтение скалярного значения